# List column changes don't apply - Is it a Sharepoint Bug?

Tags: gridview, sharepoint-2010

I have created a list in SharePoint 2010, initially had the columns Title, Mobile and Email Id.
Then I used a grid view (Visual web part) to display these fields.

Later I changed the field Title to Name and Email Id to Email. I tried accessing these fields in the grid view with new field names, however it doesn't fetch anything, only the old column names are still working. Why?

UPDATE

Of course it is not a SharePoint bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every SharePoint column (field) has three names:

- **display name** - the name that the end user sees
- **internal name** - the name that is used internally for referencing the column programmatically and throughout the database
- **static name** - the name that is used by the field type when you create custom fields

When you rename the column, you change the display name. The internal name is set when the column is created and it never changes. Thanks to this, applications don't fail when columns' names get changed and the same code can be used for sites using different languages (display name: *Title* vs. *Titel* vs. *Tytuł*, internal name: always *Title*).

You posted no code so it's a guess but it seems that **your grid view references the columns using their internal names**.

More information: [SharePoint Internal name, Static name, Display name](http://www.ukoom.com/sharepoint-internal-name-static-name-display-name.htm)

Comment: Hi Marek , Thank you for that info !! Can I edit an internal name of a column?

Comment: @Jithu No, there is no supported way to do it. Why do you need to do it? There may be a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Jithu To have "nice" internal names you should always create columns in 2 steps: **first** create a column with no special characters and spaces in its name (e.g. `LoginName_Email`), **then** rename it to whatever you need (e.g. `Login name / E-mail`). http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/sharepointer-creating-a-clean-%E2%80%9Cinternal-name%E2%80%9D-for-sharepoint-columns/

Comment: SO then I will delete and recreate it with desired name !!

Comment: @Jithu As long as the list doesn't contain a lot of items, that's the easiest way. If you create the columns programmatically, it's a good idea to have a helper method that creates the columns in a way described above.

Comment: Hi Marek, Plz do have a look at this code from Mr omlin, where he is changing the internal name, `SPListItem item = ...;
 item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "New title";
 item.Update();
`

Comment: @Jithu Where did you find this code? The internal name **is not changed** here; the code retrieves a list item, changes the value in the `Title` column to *New title* (the [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms435407.aspx) class is used) and updates the item. You need an [SPField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.aspx) object to modify a list column.